# Does Bitdefender dci network extension install a root cert and can view HTTPS Traffic?

Tags: networking

On the company issued device I can see in activity monitor:

```
com.bitdefender.cst.new.dci.dci-network-extension
```

1. What does this software do?
2. Has it installed a root certificate?
3. Can it view and filter HTTPS traffic?
4. If I view the certificate of HTTPS connections and it is for the websites domain - is that enough to prove the traffic is private?

Comment: "Has it installed a root certificate?" - The only way to "scan" HTTPS traffic is to use a TLS certificate in order to do so.  If you have the feature enabled, it will claim to be from the domain, but it will actually be a certificate installed by Bitdefender.  How those security features work are explained in detailed in numerous articles

Comment: On top of that, even if it doesn't install a root CA, it can still be able to see the data. TLS is Transport Layer Security, but when the data is on your computer, it's not in the transport layer anymore.

Comment: @mtak communication in encrypted between the application and the server

Comment: @Ramhound do you have the links to the "numerous articles"?

Comment: @tread Sure, but it isn't encrypted in the application. So whatever this software does, it can just look in the application's memory or it's files on disk, right?

Comment: @mtak Yes, however would the spying app have access/permissions to that? In this specific case when I see an app download (network usage) 1.4G of data I also see that bitdefender dci-network-extension has also used 1.4G. So all traffic first seems to go to ditdefender then to the application. Looks like a man-in-the-middle doesn't it...